# How does tensorflow scale RNNCell weight tensors when changing their dimensions?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to understand how the weights are scaled in a RNNCell when going from training to inference in tensorflow.

Consider the following placeholders defined as:

`data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None,max_seq_len])
targets = tf.placholder(tf.int32,[None,max_seq_len])`

During training the batch_size is set to 10, e.g. both tensors have shape [10,max_seq_len]. However, during inference only one example is used, not a batch of ten, so the tensors have shape [1,max_seq_len].

Tensorflow handles this dimension change seamlessly, however, I'm uncertain of how it does this?

My hypothesis is that weigth tensors, in the RNNCell, are actually shape [1,hidden_dim], and scaling to larger batch sizes is acheived by broadcasting, but I'm unable to find something that reflects this in the source. I've read through the [rnn source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py) and the [rnn cell source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py). Any help with understanding this would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is indeed via broadcasting (or "simple" tensor algebra magic where that is possible). Kinda difficult to point you to a specific code line though, because ops are actually implemented in C++ and everything above that level uses broadcasting rules for operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you have defined your `data` tensor as `data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[None,max_seq_len])` which means that the first dimension will change according to the input but the second dimension will always remain `max_seq_len`
- So if `max_seq_len = 5` than you feed shape can be either [1, 5], [2, 5], [3, 5] which means you can change the first dimension but not the second one
- If you change the second dimension to a number other than 5 then it will throw you an error for mismatch shape or similar error
- Your input's first dimension which is the batch_size won't affect the weight matrix of any of the neurons in you network